# Can we assign a source port for Kafka Producer?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I noticed that Kafka Producer uses tcp protocol.

Is there any way to fix the source ports of the multiple Kafka producers in advance?
Or at least, Is there any way I can track the source port of Kafka producer?
I need to track the bandwidth of kafka producers and consumers.
And need to set up traffic control (tc) rules according to these ports.

Comment: I don't think this is possible just using simple configuration, although it's a feature people keep asking for. The usual suggestion is to add a connection callback (https://docs.confluent.io/current/clients/librdkafka/rdkafka_8h.html#a53dd1b77019324170d0168617fdaf040) and then call `setsockopt()` on the connection socket. Although this ought to work in principle, I confess I haven't tried it.

Comment: Is there any way I can track the source port of Kafka producer? I need to track the bandwidth of kafka producers and consumers.

Comment: Use `netstat` ?

Comment: I mean, if I have dozens of producers running, can I track which producer is using a specific port, and its bandwidth?

I used iftop, which shows the producers' connections are consuming very heterogenous bandwith, with difference, e.g.,  from 2Mbps to 1Kbps.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know how to handle that situation. At the network level, all the producers are going to look the same.

Answer (score 1):

Producers don't open inbound sockets, so there is no binding of a "source port".

The only network information you must provide is `bootstrap.servers`

Comment: Is there any way I can track the source port of Kafka producer?
I need to track the bandwidth of kafka producers and consumers.

Comment: @OneCricketeer -- This isn't (I think) about inbound sockets. It's about setting a source IP and port on an _outbound_ socket. This is a legitimate operation, but one that the Kafka client (so far as I know) does not expose to users.

Comment: Exactly. Set socket address of an outbound socket.

Comment: @Ahmad As mentioned, `bootstrap.servers` is the only network information youre going to get. If you want to inspect TCP traffic on the server side, then you could add a client-id to each producer, then do extra packet inspection to see who sent what, otherwise Kafka producers expose JMX metrics for seeing much much data is being sent

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you can use something called a socket_cb() in librdKafka library
(I was using 2.0.2 version).
To achieve this u need to set

Rdkadka::Conf* globalConf = Rdkafka::Conf::create(Rdkafka::Conf::CONF_GLOBAL)

globalConf->set("socket_cb", static_castRdKafka::EventCb*(this), errstr);

And now rewrite the socket_cb() function

1. getaddrinfo() //gives list of address structure
2. socket() to get the the FD
3. bind to the selected FD

this should solve the above issue.